# BlackStack - A Stack Exchange app for BlackBerry 10

Tags: app

**BlackStack** is a native BlackBerry 10 app for browsing Stack Exchange sites like Stack Overflow, Stack Apps, and Science Fiction & Fantasy. You can view questions and answers as well as sign-in to your account to view your profile and posts.

Searches for questions, users, and tags can be made either within the app or using BlackBerry 10 features such as Universal Search and BlackBerry Assistant.

#### Download:

Download BlackStack from [BlackBerry World](https://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/59970369).

#### Screenshots:

[image: Screenshot of BlackStack's homepage with tab menu open.]
[image: Screenshot of an answer with an embedded YouTube video.]

Comment: Looks promising. ... I edited the post to put the important stuff up top (always a good SEO and/or business practice). Change it back if you don't like it.